# Upload multiple files using Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faraday

I'm trying to send a file array using Faraday with Rails. But when I send the files they arrive empty at the service that receives the files. Sending a single file works fine but with a array it doesn't.  This is an example:

```
def attachment
if @transaction.product_id == ViewTransaction::MINI

  return [Faraday::FilePart.new(File.open(CreatePdfAction.new(@transaction,'tickets').execute),
                                       'application/pdf',
                                       File.basename("Ticket")),
           Faraday::FilePart.new(File.open(CreatePdfAction.new(@transaction,'vouchers').execute),
                                               'application/pdf',
                                               File.basename("Voucher"))]
else
  return Faraday::FilePart.new(File.open(File.open(CreatePdfAction.new(@transaction,'vouchers').execute),
                        'application/pdf',
                        File.basename(template))
end

def payload(payload = {})
  payload[:attachment] = attachment
  payload[:data] = data
  payload
end
```

a this execute the http post

```
conn = Faraday.new() do |f|
  f.request :multipart
  f.adapter :net_http
end
response = conn.post("http://email-service/v1/email", payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `faraday` for upload file!

I'd recommend using `paperclip` package or this link:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html